# How to get the generative counterpart of a discriminative CNN

Tags: neural-networks, convolution

Say we train a (discriminative) CNN to predict age from images of faces. Is there a direct way of obtaining the homologous generative network (ie, from a scalar age to an image of a face) ?
The backward pass during training should be doing something similar in order to propagate the gradients from age to the face.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably no good way to do this, since it is possible to discriminate age without modeling the whole space of faces. If you also happened to have a density model of faces $X$ as well, perhaps you could use MCMC to sample from $P(X|y) \propto P(y|X)P(X)$.